# Hide thumbnail of Backend file uploader in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento's default file uploader in my custom modules. How can I hide the image thumbnail shown in image below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your form.php of your custom extention just change second argument **Image to file**

**Before**

```
   $fieldset->addField('before_image', 'image', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('testimonials')->__('Before Image'),
              'required'  => false,
              'name'      => 'before_image',
          ));
```

**After**

```
 $fieldset->addField('before_image', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('testimonials')->__('Before Image'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'before_image',
      ));
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful... But rather, I changed frontend type in my system.xml to files . It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Hello chgeck getElementHtml() function in below file

**lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/Image.php** & comment image tag
OR
skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css (line 1583) add below css

```
.v-middle {
    display: none;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```